# Android Studio Build Errors after 9 Patch pngs Added to res/drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, nine-patch

After using Android Studio's 9-patch generation tool to make a few 9 patch pngs, I get the following build errors when I try to run:
`Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:`

I've tried running `clean`, `build`,  and `Invalidate Caches / Restart` and I cant get this error to resolve! When I delete the 9 patch image from my drawable/no-dpi folder and re-add the original non-9-patch png the code compiles and runs fine. How do I fix this error?[image]

**Edit**
Using a different 9 patch image worked, so the problem seems to be with my 9 patch image I created. What's wrong with it? I want the text "Capo" to not stretch when the button is laid out vertically so I tried to make stretchy areas between that part of the image and the corners (which also shouldn't stretch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you were not creating perfect nine patch try this tutorial[Try this link for creating perfect nine patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html)

and for testing try any nine patch downloaded from Internet.

Comment: I tried using a different 9 patch image that was previously working and it worked. Can you look at  my 9 patch image in my edit and tell me what would cause it to throw that error?

Comment: I don't even know much about nine patch but past 2 and 3 weeks i have encountered the same problem so i searched for Internet and get fully prepared nine patch like i want.

Comment: That's not an option for me because i'm using a custom image I made. I have to find a way to make this image convert gracefully.

Comment: I've encountered the same its come when i convert an simple .png to nine patch using android studio but try the tutorial i  have given you it'll help u a lot.

Comment: try this link to create 9 patch online [draw nine patch online](http://draw9patch.com/#url=http://draw9patch.com/image/btn.png&top[]=25&top[]=50&right[]=25&right[]=50&bottom[]=25&bottom[]=50&left[]=25&left[]=50)

Comment: I got the tool to work in IE. The site doesn't seem to work in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio just open this image and save (Android Studio automatically use draw9patch tool).